# actualizar una columna de una tabla con el valor de otra tabla (en una columna) la cuales no estan entre si en sql

Tags: sql, plsql

junto con saludar me pueden ayuda con este problema, sucede que tengo  2 tablas: "manifiesto" y la tabla "sobretasa" la cuales  no estan relacionadas entre si (no tiene un clave primaria que las una)

esta es la tabla  manifiesto que tiene monto y una id numman y una columan recargo la cual esta vacia

[image: esta es la tabla]

esta otra es la tabla sobretasa que tiene  valor inicial y valor  final mas un pocentaje de reajuste 2000 y 2500 que multiple el monto por el porcentaje que corresponde entre esos dos valores, encontonces pense en recorrer la tabla sobretasa con un for  sobre un select y dentro ir actualizando uno por uno mi codigo es el siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

la cosa es que necesito actualizar la  columna recargo en manifiesto, en funcion del  monto por ejemplo si el monto esta entre  los valores de cada fila actualiza con el porcentaje de la derecha
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

a mi me  genera el siguiente error  como no se mucho de sql no entiendo bien que significa

a mi me genera el siguiente  error

Informe de error -
ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row
ORA-06512: at line 4
01427. 00000 -  "single-row subquery returns more than one row"
*Cause:

de antemano agradesco su ayuda

Answer (score 0):

El error lo que dice es simplemente que la subconsulta esta devolviendo mas de una fila o registro y se espera un único valor(una fila una columna).

Ahora según lo que describes deberías actualizar la tabla manifiesto realizando una subconsulta a la tabla sobretasa para obtener el porcentaje con el cual calculara el recargo(monto*porcentaje) quedando así la sentencia sql:

```sql
 update manifiesto ma set recargo = Round(monto *(select s.porc_rec from sobretasa s where s.valor_ini<=ma.monto and s.varlor_fin>=ma.monto)/100)
```

Ahora si te fija en esta sentencia sql no necesitas hacer el ciclo for debido a que la misma actualizara todas las filas o registros de la tabla manifiesto siempre y cuando en la tabla sobretasa no existan errores de data con esto me refiero a los rango de valores(valor_ini y valor_fin) que puedan hacer que la subconsulta retorne mas de una fila o ninguna